Moveit2 hybrid planning config files content
I am attempting to use hybrid planning with a ROS2 humble project for a robot with 3 degrees of freedom. From the tutorials online I can find how to set up the hybrid planning inside my launch file, but it is very hard to find an understandable generic example of how to setup the configuration files that are loaded inside the node containers for the global planned, local planner and hybrid planning. Also it is kind of not very obvious how many other "basic" configuration files do I need in the moveit_config package to make this work. do i need also a planning.yaml if i have hybrid_planning.yaml.
This might come from me not understanding the fundamentals well but if someone can point me out into a direction where i can find these generic examples of the configuration files I would really appreciate it.
Thank you.
